# What's the difference between mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit and mapred.reduce.tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

We're using Hadoop 2.7.1, and I find below 2 parameters are both set in some existing MapReduce code,

```
mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit=500
mapred.reduce.tasks=50
```

It seems the latter works, since there're 50 part-* files generated eventually.

Does anyone know the difference between thoes 2 parameters, and what would actually happen if people specify both of them? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official doc:

**mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit**

The maximum number of simultaneous reduce tasks per job. There is no limit 
if this value is 0 or negative.

> what would actually happen if people specify both of them?

Will have no effect in your example. But if you set limit to 50 and tasks to 500, hadoop will not run all 500 reducers at once, even if you cluster capacity is enough for that.

Comment: Thank you, so if I set limit to 50 and tasks to 500, 1) there would be 500 part-* files generated eventually,  2) during reducing, there would be 50 maximum reducer at the same time, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: To answer 1), no. There could be more than 500 part files. This parameter only defines how many reducers can run at the same time, not in total.

Comment: @gfytd I don't understand Ben comment, my answer is yes for both questions, number of output files is always equal to number of reducers, so you'll have 500 files at the end.